# Divisibility and Principal Ideal Domain Proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing

Let R be a ring. Show that a|b iff $b \in (a)$ iff $(b) \subseteq $ (a).

I first just want to write out what I know about this statement:

a|b means that a divides b or a is divisible by b and there exists $x \in R$ with ax=b

(a) is a principal ideal domain which is a domain in which every proper ideal can be generated by a single element

(a) can also be written as (a)=Ra

I'm just not sure how to go about this proof. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a|b$, then $b=ra$ for some $r\in R$, which means $b\in (a)$.

If $b\in (a)$, then I claim $(b)\subset (a)$. Indeed, an element of $(b)$ has the form $sb$ for some $s\in R$. Since $b\in (a)$, we must have $sb\in (a)$ also since $(a)$ is an ideal and is closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.

Finally, if $(b)\subset (a)$, then $b\in (b)\subset (a)$, and so $b= ra$ for some $r\in R$. This is the same as saying $a|b$.

This shows the first statement implies the second, which implies the third, which finally implies the first again, hence all three are equivalent.